# OpenGL FBO render different textures in different texture targets

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, fbo, render-to-texture

I'm trying to render to two different textures (`GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`, `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1`) inside my MSAA FBO, the initialization is:

```
// configure MSAA framebuffer
// --------------------------
glGenFramebuffers(1, &this->_MSAAid);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, this->_MSAAid);
// create a multi-sampled color attachment texture
glGenTextures(1, &this->_textureMultisampleID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, this->_textureMultisampleID);
glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 4, GL_RGB16F, _frameBufferSize.width, _frameBufferSize.height, GL_TRUE);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, this->_textureMultisampleID, 0);

glGenTextures(1, &this->_textureObjectIDMultisampled);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, this->_textureObjectIDMultisampled);
glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 4, GL_RGB16F, _frameBufferSize.width, _frameBufferSize.height, GL_TRUE);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, this->_textureObjectIDMultisampled, 0);

GLenum drawBuffers[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 };
glDrawBuffers(2, drawBuffers);

// create an (also multi-sampled) render buffer object for depth and stencil attachments
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &this->_renderBufferObjectID);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, this->_renderBufferObjectID);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, _frameBufferSize.width, _frameBufferSize.height);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, this->_renderBufferObjectID);

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    std::cout << "ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: MSAA Framebuffer is not complete! Error: " << glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) << std::endl;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

_frameBufferShader->use();
_frameBufferShader->setInt("screenTexture", 0);
```

then I want to copy the result inside another standard FBO, initialized like that:

```
// framebuffer configuration
// -------------------------
glGenFramebuffers(1, &this->_id);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, this->_id);

// create a color attachment texture
glGenTextures(1, &this->_textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->_textureID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, _frameBufferSize.width, _frameBufferSize.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->_textureID, 0);

glGenTextures(1, &this->_textureObjectID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->_textureObjectID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, _frameBufferSize.width, _frameBufferSize.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->_textureObjectID, 0);

GLenum drawBuffers[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 };
glDrawBuffers(2, drawBuffers);

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    std::cout << "ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: Framebuffer is not complete!" << std::endl;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

_frameBufferShader->use();
_frameBufferShader->setInt("screenTexture", 0);
```

FBO binding:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, this->_MSAAid);
glViewport(0, 0, this->_frameBufferSize.width, this->_frameBufferSize.height);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth testing (is disabled for rendering screen-space quad)

glClearColor(refreshColor.coordinates.x, refreshColor.coordinates.y, refreshColor.coordinates.z, refreshColor.coordinates.w);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
// Rendering stuff...
```

After the rendering, I want to copy both the buffers to my normal FBO:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, this->_MSAAid);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, this->_id);
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, _frameBufferSize.width, _frameBufferSize.height, 0, 0, _frameBufferSize.width, _frameBufferSize.height, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, this->_MSAAid);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, this->_id);
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, _frameBufferSize.width, _frameBufferSize.height, 0, 0, _frameBufferSize.width, _frameBufferSize.height, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
```

but for some reason what I get is that in both textures (`GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`, `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1`) the same content is written, basically, the two textures are the same, even if in my shader code I output the result into two different color attachments, here you can see my fragment shader:

```c
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;
layout (location = 1) out vec4 idColor;
  
in vec2 Frag_UV;

uniform sampler2D screenTexture;

void main()
{ 
    float gamma = 2.2;
    float exposure = 1.0;
    
    vec4 color = texture(screenTexture, Frag_UV.st);
    // HDR tonemapping
    color.rgb = vec3(1.0) - exp(-color.rgb * exposure);
    // gamma correction
    color.rgb = pow(color.rgb, vec3(1.0 / gamma));
    fragColor = vec4(color.rgb, 1.0);
    idColor = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1.0);
}
```

here is the output:

[image: output 1]

What I wish to obtain in the Scene window is to display the texture with the color attachment 0 and in the Game window the texture with the color attachment 1!

Currently these two windows shows:

- Scene Window: `textureObjectID` -> `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1`
- Game Window: `textureID` -> `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`

The result I want is to render a different texture based on the `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT`

also, I tried to debug everything with a `glReadPixel(...)` for attachment 0 and for attachment 1, and what I got is actually the same value of pixel for both textures:

[image: debugError]

This is the code I used for debugging:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, this->sceneFrameBuffer->ID);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
float pixelColor[4];
glReadPixels(Input::mouse.xPosition, Input::mouse.yPosition, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, &pixelColor);
std::cout << "Pixel Color0: ( " << pixelColor[0] << ", " << pixelColor[1] << ", " << pixelColor[2] << ", " << pixelColor[3] << " )" << std::endl;
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, this->sceneFrameBuffer->ID);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
float pixelColors[4];
glReadPixels(Input::mouse.xPosition, Input::mouse.yPosition, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, &pixelColors);
std::cout << "Pixel Color1: ( " << pixelColors[0] << ", " << pixelColors[1] << ", " << pixelColors[2] << ", " << pixelColors[3] << " )" << std::endl;
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

what am I missing? can't figure it out!

(I'm using Dear ImGui in order to display textures in the windows)

In order to give the idea of what I want to achieve, I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBR8jJg_Yfo&t=3s) that does implement the idea I wish to implement.

Comment: Remove the first three lines of the copying code.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget I already did it, and the result doesn't change, for some reason, the rendering stuff writes the output in fragColor and idColor in the same way! (without considering the idColor in the fragment shader)

Comment: Can we see the output? By the way you don't need to bind the framebuffers twice.

Comment: The names of your texture objects are very confusing also.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget here is the output: https://imgur.com/a/dLXyHMS 
What I wish to obtain it in the Scene window I want the texture with the color attachment 0 and in the Game window the texture with the color attachment 1! The names are confusing, in fact, I plan to refactor everything once I solved this issue!

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget also I tried to debug everything with a glReadPixel() for attachment 0 and for attachment 1 and what I get is pretty confusing: https://imgur.com/a/Lq0ZHRl
This is the code for debugging: https://imgur.com/a/hqe909G

Comment: Can you add all that to your question? Click the Edit text.

Comment: Please don't show text as images.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget yes, sorry, wasn't thinking about it! Quickly fixed!

Comment: Doesn't look like anything in the code you posted is wrong. Are you sure you're binding the correct texture where you're rendering to the GUI?

Comment: @TARN4T1ON Yes I double-checked it, but the texture binding is correct! I'm starting to think that it might be something related to cleaning the texture, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two frame buffers, both are used for the rendering of the scene and not of the screen (as I was mistakenly thinking), so I had to specify the color attachment output inside the shader that I use for the rendering of the objects and not the shader I'm using for the rendering of the scene over my quad (the *"screen quad"*).

Screen Fragment Shader:

```
#version 450 core

layout (location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;
  
in vec2 Frag_UV;

uniform sampler2D screenTexture;

void main()
{ 
    float gamma = 2.2;
    float exposure = 1.0;
    
    vec4 color = texture(screenTexture, Frag_UV.st);
    // HDR tonemapping
    color.rgb = vec3(1.0) - exp(-color.rgb * exposure);
    // gamma correction
    color.rgb = pow(color.rgb, vec3(1.0 / gamma));

    fragColor = vec4(color.rgb, 1.0);
}
```

Phong Fragment Shader that I'm using for the rendering of the Objects:

```
#version 450 core

layout (location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;
layout (location = 1) out vec4 idColor;

//Declaring stuff...

void main()
{
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - fs_in.FragPos);
    vec3 result = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    result += calcPointLight(material, pointLight, viewDir);

    idColor = vec4(vID);
    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
```

Now I got everything rendered to my `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1`, thanks to everyone who commented!